# How to use Jquery knob like text label with highchart Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, highcharts, jquery-knob

I am using highchart plugin and like it very much. I am using chart type: PIE , feature of highcharts. I want to add a label which displays the value of the clicked region of pie chart inside that label just like in jquery knob. for example when we click on the circular path of jquery knob it displays the value of that part.Consider http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ as an example. I want that kind of functionality in Highchart (chart type:PIE). Is there any way to do that?

here is what I want with snapshot.[image]

I want like when user click on any part like 5, 10 , 15... it displays the clicked value in that label(RED SQUARE). I am able to get the clicked value but don't know how to display that label at that place using any options of the PLUGIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch [click()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) event on the chart / [point](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) and then use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add custom text.

EDIT:
Second soluton is use pie chart with title and call setTitle function.

```
point: {
                events: {
                    click:function(){
                        var y = this.y;

                        this.series.chart.setTitle({
                            text: y
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5k86cvoe/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited my question for more clearance. Please help me with code.

Comment: Hi. I am getting what I wanted but I am getting the %age of that area in which I have clicked but I want the label of that area where I have clicked like 5,10,15,25

Comment: Co only after click on any label, center text should be updated, not you entire slice ?